# Setting up Docker Containers and Network with Terraform

Tags: docker, terraform

I'm new to Terraform and just did all the Tutorials i could find about it. I have set up Multiple Docker Containers and a Network, Currently starting it with a shell skript. The general plan would be, to be able to start my testbed and all its components with Terraform (Like ONOS with containernet, Routers, ...).

My First Question would, is Terraform made for that kind of Question? Or would you suggest anything different. I thought using Terraform would make it Easy to write new Scenarios.
AT this Point I use the Shell skripts to build and run the Docker Containers. Does it make sense to let Terraform do the RUN (not build) task?

Thanks for your Help & Opinions

I'm new to Stack, it would be awesome if you explain a downvote - so i can learn to do it better.

edit ( Build file deleted - unnecassary)

Comment: My general experience has been that Terraform is good for managing infrastructure (like cloud compute instance) but it isn't the best tool for managing software running on top of that infrastructure.  It also can't do the equivalent of `docker build` if you're not planning to use a Docker image registry.

Comment: i know that its not made for the build type. What would you suggest to run that software on top? Maybe i misunderstood you, but I want to use it for the infrastructure. I have the containers ready and just need to deploy them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The general plan would be, to be able to start my testbed and all its components with Terraform

### Tl;Dr

Don't do this.

---

This isn't what terraform is for. **Terraform provisions infrastructure**. So (as an example) if you want an azure function, you write a terraform file that d**escribes what this looks like** then run terraform to create it. **It doesn't (nor should it) run your function**. It simply describes how Azure should create these structures prior to them being ran.

It seems you actually want a build pipline that **uses** terraform as part of that process to provision the infrastructure. The **build script** would then run the containers once terraform had done it's job

Comment: Yes but as i read from the Terraform site, it also manages Platform as a Service, so i thought thats what Docker is ... What would you recommend for my usecase?

Comment: Do some googling, there are lots of tools for these kind of things. I depends on too many factors for me to say use x. A popular one is [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/)

Comment: I did a lot of researching, but i'm just starting with those tools. Missing a basic knowledge, So just to get that clear: Is it not possible to launch scripts out of Terraform that influence the docker containers!?

Comment: Thanks! I did it by creating all the containers with Terraform and access them later with something like "sudo docker exec -it #dockerID bash"