# How to use the -i or -t flag in Terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform

How do I use the -i or -t flag in Terraform?

Comment: You shouldn't be using terrafrom to launch docker. Terraform provisions infrastructure, it doesn't run it

Comment: I've answered [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595484/542251). You've wondered down a dead end here.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent to either option in the [`docker_container` resource documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/r/container.html).

If you were using Terraform to launch Docker containers, the only thing it can do for you is launch a set of background containers; there's no way to have it launch an interactive foreground container you can type into.  In most cases (one prominent React bug aside) you shouldn't need either of these options.

Comment: Thanks! I did it by creating all the containers with Terraform and access them later with something like "sudo docker exec -it #dockerID bash"